# How access xml file of "save as sample Data" in BI Publisher

Tags: bi-publisher, oracle-bi, xml-publisher

When we create data model we perform " save as sample data".
My question is how i access the xml file for uploading xml data in ms word.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sample data cannot be exported. BIP uses that sample data to show previews of reports in the catalog and some detail views. You can only use the Export button on the Data tab to get xmls from your query. So you can run a query which returns the same data as in sample data and export it out.

Answer (score 0):

Once you click on "save as sample data",you have to export the data by clicking on "export".After export it will be saved in your local system in some path.In ms word you will get an option to import xml. After clicking on that it will ask you for the path where you have saved your xml. Now you can select .click on the "field" ; you will be able to see all column details.

Answer (score 0):

[you can find the sample xml in the properties of data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nutp.jpg)
click on the text to see the screenshot